# Laptop goes to sleep then into a coma. Won't wake up by keyboard/mouse

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I reinstalled Windows 10 on my laptop and now it will not wake on keyboard/mouse after it has been asleep for a while.  I mean that if I move the mouse/keyboard 5-10 minutes after it sleeps, no problem.  Come back the next day and I have to press the power button.  Even it's own keyboard doesn't wake it.

I am using a Logitech wireless mouse/keyboard (2.4ghz) and have tried others (including wired).  This worked fine before the re-install and I didn't change and bios settings at all.  I even tried reinstalling windows again just to try to fix this issue.

Obviously I have "Allow device to wake computer" enabled or it wouldn't work initially either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal.

By default Windows will go into a "light" sleep mode. It is this mode that allows your system to wake via keyboard or other events.

After, by default, 6 hours your system will hibernate and go into a deeper sleep. In this mode it needs to be woken via the power switch.

In order to change this you need to modify your power plan. Be aware that doing so may mean that your computer will drain the battery more than normal when asleep.

From [Sleep Goes to Hibernate After Several Hours?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/sleep-goes-to-hibernate-after-several-hours/a4759d26-5a8f-407f-ba1c-ccac6c43e101?auth=1)

> For anyone else having this problem, here are clearer instructions:
>
> 1. Open Power Options by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **Control Panel** , clicking **System and Maintenance** , and then clicking
>    **Power Options**.
> 2. On the **Select a power plan** page, click **Change plan settings** under the selected plan.
> 3. On the **Change settings for the plan** page, click **Change advanced power settings**.
> 4. On the **Advanced settings** tab, expand **Sleep** , expand **Hibernate after** , and then do one of the following:
>
>    If you are using a mobile PC, click **On battery** or **Plugged in**
>    (or both), click the arrow, and then type **Never** .
> 5. Click **OK** , and then click **Save changes** .

Answer (score 1):

your computer goes to sleep after how much time is set then it goes into hibernate to save your battery.

hibernate is not a mode it just writes the contents of memory to the drive and then shuts off which is why it wont wake your computer from sleep with keyboard or mouse input because your computer is now off, so now the only way to turn your pc on would now be the power button.

i know it threw me for a loop the first time i encountered this behavior.

you can follow mokubai's instructions to disable hibernate after sleep.

i should mention hibernate can be useful so you can return to your pc just as it was in the event of a power failure/dead battery but also the downside is with todays ssd's it puts more wear and tear on your drive.